# Symfony api platform installation problem

Tags: api, symfony, composer-php

Building app with Symfony 4.4 and composer return an error in my terminal:

```
composer require api

Using version ^1.2 for api-platform/api-pack
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Restricting packages listed in "symfony/symfony" to "4.4.*"
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.6.7 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.7|~3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.6.6 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.7|~3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.6.5 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.7|~3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.6.4 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.3|~3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.6.3 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.3|~3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.6.2 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.3|~3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.6.1 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.3|~3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.6.0 requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.3|~3.0 -> no matching package found.
    - Conclusion: don't install api-platform/api-pack v1.2.1
    - Conclusion: remove doctrine/doctrine-bundle 2.0.7
    - Conclusion: don't install api-platform/api-pack v1.2.1|remove phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 5.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.1
    - Conclusion: don't install api-platform/api-pack v1.2.1|don't install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 5.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.1
    - Conclusion: don't install api-platform/api-pack v1.2.1|remove phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 5.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.1
    - Conclusion: don't install api-platform/api-pack v1.2.1|don't install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 5.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.1
    - Conclusion: don't install api-platform/api-pack v1.2.1|remove phpdocumentor/reflection-common 2.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install api-platform/api-pack v1.2.1|don't install phpdocumentor/reflection-common 2.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install api-platform/api-pack v1.2.1|remove phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 5.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.1
    - Conclusion: don't install api-platform/api-pack v1.2.1|don't install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 5.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.1
    - Installation request for symfony/framework-bundle (locked at v4.4.6, required as 4.4.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[v4.4.6].
    - Conclusion: don't install api-platform/api-pack v1.2.1|remove phpdocumentor/reflection-common 2.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.3
    - Conclusion: don't install api-platform/api-pack v1.2.1|don't install phpdocumentor/reflection-common 2.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.3
    - Installation request for phpdocumentor/reflection-common (locked at 2.0.0) -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-common[2.0.0].
    - Conclusion: don't install api-platform/api-pack v1.2.1|remove phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 5.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.1
    - Conclusion: don't install api-platform/api-pack v1.2.1|don't install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 5.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.0.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.2.3|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 3.3.2|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.0.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.1.1|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.2.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.0|install phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock 4.3.1
    - Installation request for phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock (locked at 5.1.0) -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock[5.1.0].
    - Installation request for api-platform/api-pack ^1.2 -> satisfiable by api-platform/api-pack[v1.2.0, v1.2.1].
    - Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-bundle 2.0.7
    - api-platform/api-pack v1.2.0 requires doctrine/doctrine-bundle ^1.6 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.3, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.12.4, 1.12.5, 1.12.6, 1.12.7, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.10, 1.6.11, 1.6.12, 1.6.13, 1.6.2, 1.6.3, 1.6.4, 1.6.5, 1.6.6, 1.6.7, 1.6.8, 1.6.9, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.9.0, 1.9.1].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.11.0, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.11.1, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.11.2, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.12.0, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.12.1, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.12.2, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.12.3, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.12.4, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.12.5, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.12.6, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.12.7, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.10.0, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.10.1, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.10.2, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.10.3, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.6.10, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.6.11, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.6.12, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.6.13, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.6.8, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.6.9, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.7.0, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.7.1, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.7.2, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.8.0, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.8.1, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.9.0, 2.0.7].
    - Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.9.1, 2.0.7].
    - Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-bundle (locked at 2.0.7) -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle[2.0.7].

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.
 - It's a private package and you forgot to add a custom repository to find it

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Here is my github: https://github.com/hadson82/symfonyUdemy

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: The `composer.json` in the shared repository does not match the one you are using in this question

Answer (score 0):

use the folowing command in your folder project :

```
composer require doctrine/doctrine-bundle ~2.0.7
```